# почему не работает сортировка слиянием

Tags: python, алгоритм, сортировка

Не понимаю почему не работает сортировка слиянием.Суть в том чтобы не использовать функции.

```
from random import randint
L = list(randint(1,150)for z in range(1,150))
result = []
if len(L) <= 1:
   print(L)
else:
   while len(L) > 2:
      half = len(L)//2
      left = L[:half]
      right = L[half:]
      i = 0
      j = 0
      c = 0
      while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
         if left[i] < right[j]:
            result.append(left[i])
            i = i+1
         else:
            result.append(right[j])
            j = j+1
         c = c+1

      while i < len(left):
         result.append(left[i])
         i = i+1
         c = c+1

      while j < len(right):
         result.append(right[j])
         j = j+1
         c = c+1

print(result)
```

Comment: Сортировка слиянием - рекурсивная функция. Её не получится сделать без функции, поскольку рекурсия реализуется именно через функции. Если вы хотите отсортировать список без функций, сортировка слиянием - не ваш выбор.

Comment: @Евгений Вовсе не обязательно реализовывать сортировку слиянием с помощью рекурсии. Например, можно начать с маленьких кусочков.

Comment: Вот тут не рекурсивное решение. Если не нужны функции можно вставить тело функции вместо ее вызова https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterative-merge-sort/

Comment: Функция merge вызывается в цикле. Это не рекурсия. Достаточно подставить ее код в точку вызова. Рекурсия это когда функция вызывает саму себя. Так же есть перекрестная или косвенная рекурсия, но здесь ее тоже нет, так как функция merge не вызывает других функций. Вы смотрите не ту часть примера. Смотрите ниже.

Comment: Ищите по этому фрагменту "# Iterative Merge sort (Bottom Up)"